# How to draw bounding box around symbols in binery image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, bounding-box, image-thresholding

I have an binary image as shown below:

[image: binarized image]

Now I want to draw bounding box around each character.
The best I could do using opencv contours is shown below but it is not that much accurate.

[image: Image with bounding box using contours]

as you can see this is a pure clutter? Apart from drawing contours do we have any other better option to draw the bouding box around each symbol in this picture. The target is to draw bounding box around each symbol. *Date, name, age and other information can be ignored*

Comment: That is definitely not "pure clutter"   It has identified most of the words and most of the letters.  You can tweak some of the recognition parameters, like bounding box size, but it's never going to be perfect.  You should clean up things like that edge line before you begin.

Comment: Post your code!  Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).